# How to embed one html page into another

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have two Html pages.

1. Merchant Form
2. Payment Form

The merchant form and the Payment Form are on 2 different servers.Merchant form is on server A and Payment Form is on server B.
Scenario I want.

1. The User will fill all the required fields on the merchant Form and will click on the submit button.
2. After clicking on the submit button the Payment form should open as a modal popup form.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+modal+dialog+payment+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Use an iFrame in the modal

Comment: okay, and I also want to pass some data to the payment form from the merchant form how could I achieve this @mplungjan

Comment: If you can pass it in the URL, then you can just add the parameters to the URL you load in the iFrame. If not, then you cannot, but then you couldn't do that if they were separate pages either

Comment: Okay, so I need to pass a query string in URL correctly. or is there some way where I can pass JSON data to the payment form from merchant form @mplungjan

Comment: I have not idea. Depends on the merchant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use
`<iframe></iframe>`

inside this this tag you can embed html into another html document.

Answer (score 0):

try to use iframe to embed Payment Form page from server B.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

In Merchant Form :
after fill all the required fields on the merchant Form and will click on the submit button just call the `window.open()` page which embed page from server B as pop up window.